# Flask RESTful - Waitress (Server stop to answer to request)

Tags: python, api, flask, flask-restful, waitress

I've a serious problem I'm getting crazy to solve.
I wrote a basic python API with flask.
I run it with waitress, because if I do `app.run()` it says that I should not do it because it supposed ok only for development not distribution.

This is the .py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse, abort
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import DBLayer
import os
import socket
from datetime import datetime
from waitress import serve

load_dotenv()
db_host = os.getenv('DB_HOST')
db_user = os.getenv('DB_USER')
db_pwd = os.getenv('DB_PWD')
db_port = os.getenv('DB_PORT')
db_name = os.getenv('DB_NAME')

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Version(Resource):
    def get(self):
        comando = "select * from versiondb"
        version = DBLayer.executeSQL(db_user, db_pwd, db_host, db_name, db_port, comando)

        dataAggiornamento = datetime.strptime(str(versione[0]["Validita"]), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        version[0].update({"Validita": str(dataAggiornamento)})

        if len(version) == 0:
            return "", 404
        return {"data": dict(version[0])}, 200


api.add_resource(Version, "/version")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    serve(app, host=myhost, port=5000)
```

I execute this .py on my Windows server, it works fine, but after sometimes I notice that the api is not responding anymore to the get request... so I open the Remote Desktop to take a look at what is happening... the terminal Is freezed.. I click with the mouse on the terminal, I press a random button on the keyboard, and all the request made from when it freezed to now are printed and executed in that instant, all at once... this is SO ANNOYNG

Someone can help me? please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the same exact code on a Linux based server is getting no errors.

So... I assume (after doing some research on internet) that is a Windows related issue.

Answer (score 0):

In windows, if we click within command prompt console window, the console will be in a `Quick Edit` mode, we can verify it by looking at console title bar with `Select` keyword. In order to come out of `Quick Edit` mode, we need to hit any key on the keyboard that is when all commands will be executed.

Here is how to disable this behavior:

1. Right click on the top left of the console window and select Defaults. It must be Defaults and not Properties.
2. In the Window which appears, Deselect Quick Edit. Click OK and then close the console window.
3. Open a new console window. Quick Edit should be disabled.